# Link in email to react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application

I have a problem with one thing: I want to make an application that will send email with a link to a React page with query parameters. React application is SPA, not SSR. How I can achieve that? Is this possible in React?

**Example:**

User get email with link: `http://example.com/react/messages?id={example id}`. After clicking it, he will be redirected to component Messages in React App. That component will take an id and do the rest of job.

**EDIT:**

Okay, so we start from begin:

1. I have basic spring app which only expose react app (index.html) with one component on route `/email` that only return string,
2. I have basic spring cloud gateway with customRouteLocator:

   ```
   public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
       return builder.routes()
               .route("react-app", r -> r.path("/index.html")
                       .uri("http://example-react:9001"))
               .route("react-static-files", r -> r.path("/static/**")
                       .uri("http://example-react:9001"))
               .build();
   }
   ```
3. If we write in URL - localhost:8080/index.html, then gateway will redirect us to react app

**What I want to achieve?**
When we write in URL - `localhost:8080/email` then gateway will redirect us to react app opened at email component - so react app will be started on route `/email`. Email component is not default component run on react app start. It is on route `/email`.

Comment: You can use `window.location.search` to get the query parameters from JS

Comment: Okay, but how I can make a link to concrete component in React from link in email?

Comment: In your component you can check the query parameter and render appropriately

Comment: Primary question is - how I can make a link which user will obtain in email that will redirect him to concrete component. For the first run of React application we have to run index.html, then we can route inside application. I want to make link - example.com/messages?id={id} that will do:
1. open react application
2. route to component behind messages route
3. get query param and show message with {id} (already you answered this question)
So still I don't know how to make 1st and 2nd point working.

Comment: You really haven't given enough information to answer that question. What does your router look like? You will have to check the query parameters there

Comment: Okay, why you think i didn't gave you full informations? I wrote that:

"User get email with link: http://example.com/react/messages?id={example id}. After clicking it, he will be redirected to component Messages in React App. That component will take an id and do the rest of job."

So maybe write it once again:
1. User get URL (example - example.com/messages?id={}) in his mail application,
2. User click this link,
3. Then his browser runs and open react application with route /messages,
4. React component make his job(fetch data etc.)

Comment: For the first use of React App we have to run index.html, then we can use our routes. How I can avoid that?

Comment: You are repeating the same thing you said in the question, that does not help at all. You are not required to use react router, you can route things yourself if you so perfer, based on the query parameter for example

Comment: So you can't help for me if you don't understand what I want to achieve. I think that I wrote this as simple as I can. No problem, thanks for your time and have a nice day! :)

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I'll share the React and Spring application code tonight by editing the question.

Comment: Edited question. I can't share the whole code because there is Keycloak Oauth2 under the hood. I was trying to remove it, but without success. I don't share react app code because it is simple as `npx create-react-app` with basic route to component that return string.